# MS SQL hashed password compare to plain text

Tags: java, sql-server, database, encryption, hash

I am wondering how I could get my little Program to work. All I need is when I type in my password which is **Password321!** to be compared to the hashed password in the MS SQL database under the `Password` column, I have tried to use `PWDCOMPARE('Password321!', Password);` but it didn't worked for me. It comes up with an error saying **Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'nEg5JzRQHD8P7VOwwIkeaDx6WEs=' to data type int.**
Here is my code:

```
select Password from aspnet_Membership where Password=PWDCOMPARE('Password321!', Password);
```

Please Help,

Thanks

M

Comment: You can use PWDCOMPARE('Password321!', Password) only when you know  password_hash.Because PWDCOMPARE compares your text_format password with password_hash. i.e for example 'SELECT SL.name,PWDCOMPARE('********',**SL.password_hash**) password_match
  FROM sys.sql_logins AS SL
 WHERE SL.name = 'ALogin';'

Answer (score 2):

For `SQL Server`, `PWDCOMPARE()` returns the int value `1` if the given password mataces else returns `0`

**[PWDCOMPARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd822792.aspx)**

```
Hashes a password and compares the hash to the hash of an existing password.
```

**SYNTAX:**

```
PWDCOMPARE ( 'clear_text_password', password_hash [ , version ] )
```

Returns 1 if the hash of the clear_text_password matches the password_hash parameter, and 0 if it does not.

Change your query like this,

```
SELECT Password 
FROM aspnet_Membership 
WHERE PWDCOMPARE('Password321!', Password) = 1;
```

Or you can use PWDENCRYPT()

**[PWDENCRYPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx):**

```
    Returns the SQL Server password hash of the input value that uses the current 
version of the password hashing algorithm.
```

**SYNTAX:**

```
PWDENCRYPT ( 'password' )
```

Change your query like this,

```
SELECT Password 
FROM aspnet_Membership 
WHERE Password = PWDENCRYPT('Password321!');
```

Comment: Links to relevant documentation (in the interest of showing how you knew that that's what the answer was) would make this an even better answer.

Comment: Ok I tried the : 

SELECT Password 
FROM aspnet_Membership 
WHERE PWDCOMPARE('Password321!', Password) = 1;
Output was nothing, but if you put 0 it comes with data

Next I tried was : 

SELECT Password,PWDCOMPARE('Password321!',Password) password_match
  FROM aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Users
 WHERE UserName = 'admin';

Password Match = 0;

I used the example by  Prakhar Asthana, for the sa and that returned 1. all I have done is, use the membership from asp.net by using the aspnet_regsql.exe then use the CreateUserWizard from asp.net toolbox and made an account with the Password but no match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server to authenticate users you should attempt to utilize best practices to minimize the possibility of SQL Injection in your web server.

The query below is a good example of using SHA1 authentication to authenticate users on login.
Note, its not a java implementation but it should give you a good idea of what you are doing wrong.

```
sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_level 
        FROM users
        WHERE user_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'
        AND user_pass = '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've just removed MD5 Hash from my site and now using SHA-256 which will be better for me. SHA1 will discontinue in 2016 or 2017 as I have read on the internet. Also I will try to do the sql statements with form to have less issues with SQL Injection on MS SQL.